# Server Side Validation Logic

Tags: firebase

I am creating some kind of quiz where I ask the user questions, which she needs to answer and if all are answered correctly, I want to display a success-message with instructions for where to get a reward.

My application is an Angular-Firebase-Application (Progressive Web App, PWA) and entirely writtein in TypeScript. Serverside is a Firebase-Hosted Web-App with FireStore Database.

Because "clients are evil", I don't want to simultaneously download the correct answers (and the success message) to the client and check the validity of the user's answers on the client - I'd rather send the user's answers to the server, which checks them and only if right, sends back the success-message.

How is this accomplished in firebase?

Sidenote: My users are not logged-in in any form and are therefore completely anonymous.

Comment: Can you add more details? How does your server work like or do you store questions and which language it is written in and so on?

Comment: Thanks. But I meant have you written any API for backend which fetch questions and validate any incoming requests? The details you've shared are about your frontend app mostly.

Comment: It is a Firebase-Application (Firebase is a Backend as a Service - BaaS). There is only client-side-code right now. That's why I ask how this would be accomplished with that kind of technology.

Comment: Oh okay - understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using one of Firebase's databases (Realtime Database or Firestore) to store the answers, you can [use security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) to protect access to the data on the server. If the answers are write-in (as opposed to multiple choice), you can then combine those two to implement the use-case.

An example of the data structure in Realtime Database could be:

```
{
  Question: "What is NoRyb's user ID on Stack Overflow?"
  Answer: {
    "1288552": "Yes indeed. NoRyb's user ID is 1288552!"
  }
}
```

If we then protect access to this with the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "Question": {
      ".read": true
    },
    "Answer": {
      "$id": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules:

- Every user can read the question.
- No one can read the `Answer` node itself.
- To be able to read the answer, you must know its key (`"1288552"`).

There are many variations on this scheme, including allowing users to increment their score if they also write their UID under the correct answer. The limit is usually how much effort you're willing to spend, and how willing you are to change your data structure to fit the use-case with only client-side code.

---

Unrelated: in order to be able to identify your users without requiring them to sign in, have a look at Firebase's [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

Comment: Thanks - I like this option. BTW I'm using a Firestore Database. Thanks also for the (unrelated) link to the anonymous auth.

Comment: You could do the same for Firestore with its security rules, so 